Cordova installation on Windows - missing requirements
I'm trying to install Cordova on a Windows environment and so far I haven't managed to meet all the requirements.
This is what I get with cordova requirements
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 22.0.1
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
'avdmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: not installed
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
Some of requirements check failed

Let's start with Gradle.
I can see Gradle inside Android Studio

I have also installed in manually in c:\gradle

I have added the path in my environment variables:

But Gradle is still not detected by Cordova
Now, let's tackle Android Target
According the Android Developer site, I need to go to Android Studio > Tools > Android SDK manager but this option is simply not there. I'm using Android Studio 2023.3.1 which seems to be the last version.
I have Android SDK in languages and framework:

am I missing something somewhere to meet the requirements?
Thanks

avdmanager is part of the SDK commandline tools. You also need to install one of the Android platforms to build against. You need to add the Gradle bin directory to your PATH environment variable, not GRADLE_HOME (I guess)

I managed to get things working by adding the following in PATH:

I also had to install manually Android SDK tools and Android SKD Command line through Android studio
